# "Canonical" form for gauge equivalence classes of matrices in $\mathfrak{gl}_n(x)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, differential-equations, differential-algebra

Let $\mathfrak{gl}_n(x)= \mathfrak{gl}_n \otimes_\mathbb{C}\mathbb{C}(x)$ be the algebra of matrices taking values in rational functions.

> **Definition:** Two matrices $A, B \in \mathfrak{gl}_n(x)$ are said to be **gauge equivalent** iff there exists an invertible matrix $P \in
>  {GL}_n(\mathbb{C}(x))$ satisfying: $$B=PAP^{-1}+P'P^{-1}$$

The above is easily seen to be an equivalence relation on the matrices in $\mathfrak{gl}_n(x)$.

The classical Jordan decomposition for complex scalar matrices gives a canonical (modulo transposition of blocks) representative for every equivalence class of matrices for the equivalence relation of **similarity**. My question is basically "is there a similar thing for this case and if there is what is it?".

> **Question:** Can one define a "canonical form" for matrices in $\mathfrak{gl}_n(x)$ modulo gauge equivalence? That is a **sensible and computable** assignment of a **canonical representative matrix** for every **gauge equivalence class** in $\mathfrak{gl}_n(x)$

If the above is some kind of extremely difficult untractable super-problem I'd appreciate an answer which explains why is this the case and additionally:

> If the above is hopless can this be done at least for $\mathfrak{gl}_n \otimes_\mathbb{C}\mathbb{C}((x))$? With $P$ above lying in $GL_n(\mathbb{C}((x)))$ of course.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the relation you want?  It should be $$ A = P^{-1}BP + P^{-1}\,P', $$ shouldn't it?

Comment: @RobertBryant Previous version was indeed wrong. Now I set it up so that one gets the expression for $B$ by putting $P(\partial - A)P^{-1}=(\partial - B)$. The expression you mention probably comes from a different convention.

Comment: Rewrite the equation as $P' = BP - PA$. Use the usual ODE theory to solve for $P$. Since the equation is linear, the solution exists globally, on any simply connected domain. If your domain has closed loops, then the holonomy of $\partial -A$ and $\partial -B$, seen as flat connections, must agree, otherwise your solution will be at most multivalued.

Comment: @Igor Khavkine What does this do? Takes two given matrices A and B which are locally gauge equivalent and finds a gauge transformation between them? That's not really the topic of the question.

Comment: @SaalHardali, If the solution exists for $A=0$ (modulo holonomy constraints) then zero is your canonical form.

Comment: @SaalHardali:  Yes, the equation I wrote down is the same as the corrected equation you wrote down when you replace $P$ by $P^{-1}$ and $A$ and $B$ by their negatives.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine This doesn't actually work the way you want it to because Saal Hardari demands that $P'$ be a rational function. Consider the differential equation $\partial -1$, say, which is defined on the simply-connected domain $\mathbb C$ but is not equivalent to $\partial - 0 $ in this sense. This is why I think the question should probably be in the algebraic-geometry tag.

Comment: @WillSawin, yes, you are of course right. Though working over $\mathbb{C}((x))$ does remove this limitation. So at least the second part of the question is answered.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Not so fast - consider $\delta - 1/x^2$, whose solution $e^{1/x}$ cannot be expressed as a Laurent series around zero. The fact that this phenomenon (exponentials of polynomials) is pretty much "the only obstruction" is what is discussed, I believe, in the reference I gave in my answer.

Comment: Haha, silly me, forgot the difference between $\mathbb{C}((x))$ (Laurent series) and $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ (formal power series)! So yes, excellent point.

Answer (score 4):

For your second question, you may want to look at "Jordan decomposition for a class of singular differential operators" by A. H. M. Levelt, https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.afm/1485896417

The only difference with your problem is that he allows gauge transformations by an extension of the Laurent series field.